# Find corresponding Servlet for JSP

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I am new to `Java EE`, coming from a `.NET` background. I am working on this project where I am back-tracking from the UI to understand the flow of code to see how the data is being populated in the `JSP` file. The logic behind the code is that the data is pulled from the database depending on what item is selected from the `dropdown` menu. Then, the data is added to an `model` object, and is sent to the `JSP` file to be shown in a table. The problem that I am facing is that, I am unable to find the `Servlet` where the `model object` is filled with data from the database, and is sent to this `JSP` file to be shown on the UI. I was able to identify the `JSP` by searching for the `id` of the `dropdown` which I got from `inspect-element` from the browser.

I checked `web.xml` for `<servlet-mapping></servlet-mapping>` tags, but there was none for this `JSP file`. Am I missing a concept here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<!--mapping-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will find something like this

Comment: This is what I had mentioned in my question, the `web.xml` does not contain any reference to the `.jsp` file. There is no `<servlet></servlet>` or `<servlet-mapping></servlet-mapping>` tags for this `.jsp` file.

Comment: thats the only way, in big projects developer creates another xml and import to web.xml, just check the code